# Unmet dependencies for MySQL Workbench

Tags: 20.04, dependencies, mysql-workbench

```
Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them, since they are a common source of problems.
Furthermore run the following command in a Terminal: apt-get install -f
Transaction failed: The package system is broken
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:

mysql-workbench-community: Depends: libmysqlclient21 (>= 8.0.11) but it is not installed
                           Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 9) but 10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04 is installed
                           Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.0) but 1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu1.1 is installed
```

Comment: Uninstall whatever non-Ubuntu packages you recently installed to restore your package manager to working condition. Review `/var/log/apt/history.log` and `/var/log/apt/history.log.1.gz` of you do not recall what you installed that caused the problem.

Comment: I am noob in ubuntu. Which command i check that?

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache policy mysql-workbench-community zlib1g`?

Comment: @Kulfy mysql-workbench-community:
  Installed: 8.0.22-1ubuntu20.04
  Candidate: 8.0.22-1ubuntu20.04
  Version table:
 *** 8.0.22-1ubuntu20.04 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
zlib1g:
  Installed: 1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu1.1
  Candidate: 1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu1.1
  Version table:
 *** 1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu1.1 500
        500 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu1 500
        500 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages

Comment: @PatrykKożuchowski Consider appending that in the question. Formatting in comments make outputs difficult to read.